# Transmission api setting wrong To header when specify header_to with multiple recipients

Tags: go, sparkpost

I'm trying to send an email to multiple people(multiple to addresses) and have them all listed in the email clients like a regular email. When I set the `header_to` field on all recipients to `email1@foo.com, email2@foo.com` I end up with emails that have a to header set to `"First Name" <email1@foo.com, email2@foo.com>` which is incorrect.

This shows up as a single person with multiple email addresses in most clients and the header is wrong.

Why is the sparkpost transmission api messing with the `header_to` field? It's docs say that it uses this in place of generating a To header for you.

Answer (score 1):

After going through every page of docs I could find to try and figure out how sparkpost's backend works I've found that you must omit the `Name` field on all recipients.

https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/recipient-lists/#header-recipient-object[image: bad sparkpost header to]